# Trigger nodejs simple-ssh for a long running command and come out

Tags: python, node.js, bash, express, ssh

I'm trying to trigger a bash script which runs for hours on my remote server using npm module "**simple-ssh**". But, I don't want to wait till the completion of the bash script execution. I want to continue to my next chain the exec and end the ssh session. As my bash script is running in the background, I expect it to complete gracefully even if I end my ssh session.

Problem is I'm unable to achieve this as the control never gets out of first block in the chain till the bash script completion is done. Please suggest a way to perform this goal.

**server.js**

```
const sh_script = 'sh /ws/jobs/test.sh'

var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
var ssh = new SSH({
    host: 'HOST IP',
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password'
});

ssh
  .exec(sh_script, {
    out: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
    },
  })
  .exec('echo "exiting shell"',{
    out: function(){
        ssh.end();
        console.log("exiting");
    }
  })
  .start();
```

**test.sh (This shell script takes hours to complete)**

```
function start_ui_validation {
  ......
}

echo "Before starting subshell"
(
    start_ui_validation "params"
) &
echo "Finished"
```

Comment: This isn't related to Python, correct?

Comment: Sorry for tagging it wrong. I tried a Python subprocess for background execution. Forgot to add that code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are trying to execute `sh /ws/jobs/test.sh` is running in foreground, that's why the control is not returning to your subsequent `.exec()`s. You'd need to put your previous process in background for the control to return to you. This can be easily achieved by `nohup`. try changing your `sh_script` to something like this:

```
sh_script = 'nohup /ws/jobs/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &';
```

`nohup` will start your process detached from your ssh session. `>/dev/null 2>&1` will redirect stdout and stderr from the process to `/dev/null` and the `&` in the end will put your process in background. After this the control should return back to your code, and next exec should continue.

There are other ways of achieving this without nohup (in case you do not have nohup on your remote system). You could do `sh_script = 'sh /ws/jobs/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &';` which starts the script in background and then add another `.exec('disown', {out:function() {}})` which will disconnect the last process from your ssh session. Use this only if nohup is not available for some reason.

Comment: nohup /ws/jobs/test.sh >/dev/null did the trick. Redirecting stderr, stdout again gave me "Ambiguous output redirect" error. Thanks again for the suggested solution.